# Kotlin, Android - How to transform MutableLiveData<MutableList< something >> to LiveData<List< something >>

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelist

in the ViewModel I have `MutableLiveData<MutableList<object>>` and I want to create **`LiveData<List<object>>`**, but I don't know how to create `List` from `MutableList`.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class AppViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _tasks = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Task>>(mutableListOf())
    val tasks: LiveData<List<Task>> = _tasks
}
```

(but I'm getting error *Type mismatch. Required: LiveData<List> Found: MutableLiveData<MutableList>*)

When I change the `val tasks: LiveData<List<Task>> = _tasks` to `val tasks: LiveData<MutableList<Task>> = _tasks` it works, but I want the `List` in tasks **not to be editable**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LiveData is defined in Java, where there is no declaration-site variance. (If it were defined in Kotlin, they maybe would have made the type covariant `out` to avoid this problem.) To get around it, you can use use-site variance to make it covariant:

```
val tasks: LiveData<out List<Task>> = _tasks
```

Covariant means you can't modify its contents from this reference, which is already true of read-only LiveData. This just makes it known to the compiler. Marking it covariant allows the the up-casting of the MutableList type to List type.

Comment: Thank you, your solution got me rid of the error :-) Great!

Comment: Follow up question :-)... I'm using dataBinding... but it looks like I cannot access the items in list like this outside the ViewModel (I thought it is accesible from anywhere):
`tasks.value.get(index)` etc.
The _value_ option is not there and it's error then...

Comment: Sorry, I've never used data binding.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your solution it helped :-)